# HttpClient get call using asp net core 3.1 connection attempt failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing an application which is asp.net core 3.1 mvc application consuming .net core 2.1 api. On local host it working fine but when I publish my web application and try to call httpclient get call it gives me this error.

[image]

Here is my start up code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; // <-- ! long.MaxValue
                options.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });
           services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services
                .AddHttpClient<ApiClient>(opts =>
                {
                    opts.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://falcon****-***-******.com"); /// --- base server url which my apiclient can hit.
                });
            services.Configure<SettingDTO>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                 .AddCookie(options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                 });
            ResolverService.RegisterModelServices(services, Configuration);
        }
```

Here is my my api server link I kept it in appSettings

> ```
> "WebApiBaseUrl": "http://falcon****-001-***.***.com/api/"
> ```

Here is my api client method.

```
private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri requestUrl, string urlParams)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{requestUrl}?{urlParams}", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resp);
        }
```

I don't where I am doing it wrong but it is not working when I publish it. On local it is working fine.

Comment: Is server expecting a HTTP or HTTPS( secure).  Mosrt servers these days only allow a secure connection and your URL is http (not https).

Comment: Yes basically I am using http not https.

Comment: SSL enabled has to be false if you are not using https.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

Comment: Should I have to disabled ssl from api application or the web application which is consuming api?

Comment: Can I disabled using web config because we are using smarterasp for both applications. The APi application and the web application

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iis